# When Jesus says "Come to me all you who are weary and heavy-laden," is he identifying himself as the Messiah by comparing himself with David?

Tags: david, messiah

In [Matthew 11:28‭-‬30](https://bible.com/bible/59/mat.11.28-30), Jesus says, "Come to me, all who labor and are heavy laden, and I will give you rest." This language reflects [1 Samuel 22:2](https://bible.com/bible/59/1sa.22.2), where David gathered men who were in distress, in debt, and bitter in soul.

It also reflects [1 Samuel 22:23](https://bible.com/bible/59/1sa.22.23), when David offers his protection to the priest Abiathar, after Doeg the Edomite had massacred the other priests.

Is Jesus making a messianic claim by making a reference to David gathering his men?

Comment: Based on my intuition,  Matthew 11:28‭-‬30 is much more broader, and has much more to do with Jesus Christ, The True Lord & Saviour, trying to notify all those affected by affliction & suffering that He can comfort & give them rest.  I think that David being leader of those who are in distress is just a sign of David being a leader who himself is in distress, and therefore leads others who are in distress.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but only typologically, for historical DavI’d soothed those afflicted by earthly calamities, whereas the promised Davidic Messiah whom historical David regards and worships as Lord (Psalm 110:1) soothes people from both bodily and spiritual afflictions of sins, which only God can do, and thus it signifies Christ’s divinity and resonates perfectly with the Isaiah’s: “Come now, let us settle the matter,” says the Lord: “Though your sins are like scarlet, they shall be as white as snow; though they are red as crimson, they shall be like wool.” (Isaiah 1:18).